# jQuery Scroll Event Exception

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a parent div (id showmenu) within which there is another div (class menu). The menu div is hidden by default and scrolls up or down on showmenu mouseclick. Till here it works fine.

Now, I do not want the menu div to scroll up if any of the links within the menu are clicked.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="showmenu" style="background-color:#cccccc;padding:10px;">
    Click Anywhere
    <div class="menu" style="display: none;">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="linkclass">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="linkclass">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="linkclass">Link3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, this is the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
        $('.menu').toggle("scroll");
    });
});
```

I do not want the menu div to scroll up if clicking on the menu links and the menu div should scroll up if clicked anywhere else within the showmenu div.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showmenu').click(function () {
        $('.menu').toggle("scroll");
    });
    $(".linkclass").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        // Do something
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/xr4907bk/)

[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: Great! This is what I actually was looking for. Thank you very much for the demo as well. Cheers!! :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu a').click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

This code will ensure that the `showmenu`'s `click()`is not called when the links are clicked, thus preventing the scroll.